# How to run sonarQube on real iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am able to run sonarqube in my simulator with following code in sonar-project.properties file

```
sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12,OS=14.4
```

But my project need real device to run , as it doesnt support simulator due to camera and all.
So i read some pages in google and updated above line for real device like this

```
sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS,name=NKP's iPhone 12,OS=14.4
```

but this throwing following error when i do `./run-sonar-swift.sh`

```
Error:

NKP-mac:S nkp$ ./run-sonar-swift.sh
Running run-sonar-swift.sh...
2021-04-29 10:27:53.255 defaults[4216:1634792] 
The domain/default pair of (/Users/nkp/Desktop/demo/8April/testfolder/S/S/Info.plist, CFBundleShortVersionString) does not exist
.Extracting Xcode project information........................................................................xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS, name:NKP's iPhone 12 }

    The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

    Available destinations for the "S" scheme:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9C9A7543-0D97-441C-8DE3-B0041B4CA2C1, OS:14.4, name:iPad (8th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6134D34F-09FD-4917-BF54-5F0A3E18F0D2, OS:14.4, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2D4C5888-6A02-4F9B-87DD-F8FA263110D1, OS:14.4, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7C119D1E-86B1-4EF7-B4C2-1E213415E66E, OS:14.4, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:533BA97B-F160-4EDD-8872-F748A98E8E9F, OS:14.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0C96D052-EF18-46E8-BF01-D53A7562A76A, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 8 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:08DB4050-DFBF-4E05-B87F-3E41C2A8DB74, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D72B679E-C25A-4532-ACC2-3E200A237D67, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 11 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E11B90D0-CFA3-4085-BE8C-0F750927DEDD, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C3164B36-ECAC-44D6-A7E8-6BFE11CC0D93, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E40BD51E-8D17-4547-B473-15C82C6EC304, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 12 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:73829CC5-70D1-47AB-8F94-A1F58186EB89, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4524DDE1-8AA6-4A21-8A80-1E7B34C0BFA3, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2176C85C-FB2E-488A-A515-C131BC4AE5F3, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 12 mini }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5DF4F47-8F8F-4807-9CCA-35CBAE766F73, OS:14.4, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9C140F00-B361-4F4E-B939-644A02FD70C9, OS:14.4, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }

    Ineligible destinations for the "S" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
ERROR - Command 'xcodebuild clean build -workspace S.xcworkspace -scheme S -destination platform=iOS,name=NKP's iPhone 12 -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO' failed with error code: 70
NKP-mac:S nkp$
```

Can anyone know how to run SonarQube on iOS real device ?
It will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

`sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS,name='device-name'` worked for me